# Python shortest regex match does not seem to yield correct answer,

Tags: python, regex

For text

```
In <TIMEX3 tid="t4" type="DATE" value="2013-03-21">the 90 years</TIMEX3> since Rebecca Felton of Georgia became the first woman in the United States Senate - sworn in for a mere <TIMEX3 tid="t5" type="DATE" value="2013-03-21">24 hours</TIMEX3> - women remain an anomaly in the upper chamber.
```

The regex

```
re.sub(r"<TIMEX3 .*?>24 hours</TIMEX3>", "24 hours", text)
```

Should yield

```
In <TIMEX3 tid="t4" type="DATE" value="2013-03-21">the 90 years</TIMEX3> since Rebecca Felton of Georgia became the first woman in the United States Senate - sworn in for a mere 24 hours - women remain an anomaly in the upper chamber.
```

Since I am matching the shortest possible match (.*?)
However, it generates

```
In 24 hours - women remain an anomaly in the upper chamber.
```

Would be grateful for any guidance on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The input does not match regex? what is `<TIMEX3`

Comment: And what you want to end up with seems identical to what you started with, so what is the point?

Comment: `.*?` does not mean "the shortest possible match". That's an oversimplification that leads to exactly this kind of misunderstanding.

Comment: @Booboo: I'm basically trying to strip out the </TIMEX> from 24 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `.*?` with `[^>]+`:

```
import re

text = '''
In <TIMEX3 tid="t4" type="DATE" value="2013-03-21">the 90 years</TIMEX3> since Rebecca Felton of Georgia became the first woman in the United States Senate - sworn in for a mere <TIMEX3 tid="t5" type="DATE" value="2013-03-21">24 hours</TIMEX3> - women remain an anomaly in the upper chamber.
'''
print re.sub(r"<TIMEX3 [^>]+>24 hours</TIMEX3>", "24 hours", text)
```

**Output:**

```
 In <TIMEX3 tid="t4" type="DATE" value="2013-03-21">the 90 years</TIMEX3> since Rebecca Felton of Georgia became the first woman in the United States Senate - sworn in for a mere 24 hours - women remain an anomaly in the upper chamber.
```

Comment: @BarunPatra: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't get the proper output because you have given Substring needed to be replaced in falsive way.

You have to use the Any character operator('.') in between the substring end

> Updated Code:

```
import re   #import regex library

#define sample text
text = 'In <TIMEX3 tid="t4" type="DATE" value="2013-03-21">the 90 years</TIMEX3> since Rebecca Felton of Georgia became the first woman in the United States Senate - sworn in for a mere <TIMEX3 tid="t5" type="DATE" value="2013-03-21">24 hours</TIMEX3> - women remain an anomaly in the upper chamber.'

#performing substitution
result_text = re.sub(r"<TIMEX3 .*.>24 hours</TIMEX3>", "24 hours", text)
print(result_text)    #displaying resulting text
```

> Output:

```
In 24 hours - women remain an anomaly in the upper chamber.
```

I hope it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is missing the `'/'` before the closing `'</TIMEX3>'` tag. You can optimize it as well in regards to only matching the shortes tag:

```
r"<TIMEX3[^>]+?>24 hours</TIMEX3>"
```

where

```
[^>]+?
```

matches only the shortest amount of letters after `'<TIMEX3'` up to the next `'>'`.

```
text = """In <TIMEX3 tid="t4" type="DATE" value="2013-03-21">the 90 years</TIMEX3> since Rebecca Felton of Georgia became the first woman in the United States Senate - sworn in for a mere <TIMEX3 tid="t5" type="DATE" value="2013-03-21">24 hours</TIMEX3> - women remain an anomaly in the upper chamber."""

import re

r = re.sub(r"<TIMEX3[^>]+?>24 hours</TIMEX3>", "24 hours", text)

print(r)
```

Output:

```
In <TIMEX3 tid="t4" type="DATE" value="2013-03-21">the 90 years</TIMEX3> since Rebecca Felton of Georgia became the first woman in the United States Senate - sworn in for a mere 24 hours - women remain an anomaly in the upper chamber.
```